# Cassandra read perfomance slowly decreases over time

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have a Cassandra cluster that consists of six nodes with 4 CPUs and 16 Gb RAM each and underlying shared storage (SSD). I'm aware that shared storage considered a bad practice for Cassandra, but ours is limited at the level of 3 Gb/s on reads and seems to be reliable against exigent disk requirements.

The Cassandra used as an operational database for continuous stream processing.

Initially Cassandra serves requests at `~1,700 rps` and it looks nice:

[image: Initial rate]

The initial `proxyhistograms`:

[image]

But after a few minutes the perfomance starts to decrease and becomes more than three times worse in the next two hours.

At the same time we observe that the `IOWait` time increases:

[image]

And `proxyhistograms` shows the following picture:

[image: proxyhistograms]

We can't understand the reasons that lie behind such behaviour. Any assistance is appreciated.

**EDITED:**

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subject.record(
    subject_id UUID,
    package_id text,
    type text,
    status text,
    ch text,
    creation_ts timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY((subject_id, status), creation_ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (creation_ts DESC);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subject.c_record(
    c_id UUID,
    s_id UUID,
    creation_ts timestamp,
    ch text,
    PRIMARY KEY(c_id, creation_ts, s_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (creation_ts DESC);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subject.s_by_a(
    s int,
    number text,
    hold_number int,
    hold_type text,
    s_id UUID,
    PRIMARY KEY(
        (s, number),
        hold_type,
        hold_number,
        s_id
    )
);
```

Comment: Does `tablehistograms` show anything about how large the partitions are?  Also, what is the table definition?

Comment: Hi @Aaron
The partitions are quite small, far from 100 Mb each. I will be able to edit the post with additional DDLs later today, thanks.

Comment: @Aaron I've updated the question with DDLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> far from 100 Mb

While some opinions may vary on this, keeping your partitions in the 1MB to 2MB range is optimal.  Cassandra typically doesn't perform well when returning large result set.  Keeping the partition size small, helps queries perform better.

Without knowing what queries are being run, I *can* say that with queries which deteriorate over time... *time* is usually the problem.  Take this PRIMARY KEY definition, for example:

```
PRIMARY KEY((subject_id, status), creation_ts)
```

This is telling Cassandra to store the data in a partition (hashed from a concatenation of `subject_id` and `status`), then to sort and enforce uniqueness by `creation_ts`.  What can happen here, is that there doesn't appear to be an inherent way to *limit* the size of the partition.  As the clustering key is a timestamp, each new entry (to a particular partition) will cause it to get larger and larger over time.

Also, `status` by definition is temporary and subject to change.  For that to happen, partitions would have to be deleted and recreated with every status update.  When modeling systems like this, I usually recommend `status` columns as non-key columns with a secondary index.  While secondary indexes in Cassandra aren't a great solution either, it can work if the result set isn't too large.

With cases like this, taking a "bucketing" approach can help.  Essentially, pick a time component to partition by, thus ensuring that partitions cannot grow infinitely.

```
PRIMARY KEY((subject_id, month_bucket), creation_ts)
```

In this case, the application writes a timestamp (`creation_ts`) and the current month (`month_bucket`).  This helps ensure that you're never putting more than a single month's worth of data in a single partition.

Now this is just an example.  A whole month might be too much, in your case.  It may need to be smaller, depending on your requirements.  It's not uncommon for time-driven data to be partitioned by week, day, or even hour, depending on the required granularity.

Comment: Hi @Aaron

I highly appreciate your detailed answer. We have some new considering the issue. We used a replication factor of three for the most keyspaces. Recently we've decreased the factor to one and the mystical disk reads seems to dissapeared. Does it makes sense?